# Java 8 eclipse error when running application

Tags: java, eclipse, 2d-games

Not seeing any errors or warning just the following within the console:

Any suggestions? I haven't the slightest idea of what is preventing the project from compiling.

[image]

Comment: Those are the errors. Runtime Exceptions.

Comment: Your program is trying to load images from files located at certain URLs, and the program is unable to access the URLs.

Comment: Your code is compiling fine, you just have bugs to fix.